# Convert Fahrenheit to Celsius Python

Tags: python

I have been trying to convert Celsius and Fahrenheit and currently having problems with  Fahrenheit to celsius , the code for the formula doesn't work for Fahrenheit to Celsius and I have no idea why

:

```
Fahrenheit = 69
Celsius = (5/9*Fahrenheit - 32)
print(Celsius)
```

However, whenever I do celsius to Fahrenheit, it works.

```
Celsius = 1
Fahrenheit = (9/5*Celsius + 32)
print(Fahrenheit)
```

Comment: "currently having problems with fahrenheit to celsius". Can help explain the problem? Not good to expect us to test your code to come up with the problems

Comment: Where does that `n` come from?

Comment: What is `n`? The formula you appear to be using to convert Fahrenheit to Celsius isn't correct. The relationship you want is `C = (F-32) * (5/9)`

Comment: The problem is that the code for the formula doesn't work for Fahrenheit to celsius, I have no idea why.

Comment: The formula doesn't work because it isn't correct. Where did you get `C = F - (32 * 1.625)` from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

int(n) seems like it shouldn't be there.

Another issue is that you should watch out for the order of operations because the multiplication will be executed before the subtraction. So to do the subtraction first, you should use parentheses.

this should give you the result you're looking for:

```
Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5 / 9
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem comes from not understanding [operator precedence](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence).
Division and multiplication come before subtraction so in this code:

```
Celsius = (5/9*Fahrenheit - 32)
```

You are doing `5/9 * Fahrenheit` first then subtracting `32`. You need to subtract before multiplying so changing it to this should give the right result:

```
Celsius = 5/9 * (Fahrenheit - 32)
```

Notice that you didn't have the problem the other way around because the multiplication should indeed happen before the addition. You can still add parenthesis (even if not needed) to make it clearer to the reader:

```
Fahrenheit = (9/5 * Celsius) + 32
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code should look something like this [ANSWER]:

```
celsius = float(input("Enter temperature in celsius: "))
fahrenheit = (celsius * 9/5) + 32
print(str(celsius) + " Celsius is: " + str(fahrenheit) + " Fahrenheit")
```

There are many variations on how to code this particular program so do what's best for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Fahrenheit = 77
Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5.0/9.0
print(Celsius)
```

The formula in your question is incorrect.

Comment: Yes, I think that was stated initially conversion programs can get quite confusing! :)

Comment: There's no need to change the `int` literals from the OP's code to `float`s on Python 3 (the only supported version of the language at present); `int / int` already produces `float` results (and I believe does so more accurately than `float`s will in some cases, as it tries to stay lossless as long as possible).

Answer (score 0):

you can use function `def` to calculate fahrenheit and celsius, such as:

```
def Fahrenheit_toCelsius(Fahrenheit):
    Celsius = (Fahrenheit - 32) * 5/9
    return Celsius
    
def Celsius_toFahrenheit(Celsius):
    Fahrenheit = (Celsius * 9/5) + 32
    return Fahrenheit
```

Then, you can call the function, just like :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Fahrenheit_toCelsius(10))
    print(Celsius_toFahrenheit(10))
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a method for recipe tutorial steps

```
def convert_substrings_to_celsius(instruction_step: str):
    """
    Find strings in an instruction step that need to be converted to Celsius 
    Examples: "350°F" or "350 F" or "350F"
    or "350°Fahrenheit" or "350 Fahrenheit" or "350 grad" or "350 Grad Fahrenheit"
    :param instruction_step:
    :return: instruction_step
    """
    def conversion(value):
        value = float(value)
        celsius = (value - 32) * 5.0 / 9.0
        # Round to the closest ten
        rounded_celsius = round(celsius, -1)
        return str(int(rounded_celsius))

    # Split the instruction step into single strings
    single_strings = instruction_step.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(single_strings)):
        # split strings containing a number and "F" or "f" at the end
        if any(char.lower() == "f" for char in single_strings[i]) and any(char.isdigit() for char in single_strings[i]):
            # Split the string into parts containing the number and "F" or "f"
            number, f_char = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, single_strings[i])), ''.join(filter(str.isalpha, single_strings[i]))
            # Add the split parts back to the list
            single_strings[i] = f"{number} {f_char}"
        # Check if the current string contains "°" or "grad" or "F" in a case-insensitive manner
        if any(substr in single_strings[i].lower() for substr in {"°", "grad", "f"}):

            # Find the digit before "°" or "grad"
            digit = ''.join(filter(str.isdigit, single_strings[i - 1]))
            if digit:  # Check if there's a digit
                single_strings[i - 1] = conversion(digit)
                if "F" == single_strings[i]:
                    single_strings[i] = "°C"

    # Convert back to string
    instruction_step = " ".join(single_strings)

    # Look for strings "°F" or "Fahrenheit" and change it to "°C" or "Celsius"
    if "°F" in instruction_step or "Fahrenheit" in instruction_step:
        instruction_step = instruction_step.replace("°F", "°C").replace("Fahrenheit", "Celsius")

    return instruction_step
```